# How to create readable subfolder in Magento root

Tags: magento-1.9, custom

So, I am working with Magento 1.9 and I want to create a new subfolder in the Magento root in order to put my scripts.

The matter is, in localhost everything is working fine. I can browse /scripts without any problem. However, when I try to access /scripts from the website Magento root I get 403 error forbidden.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

I tried to copy the live website .htaccess in the localhost but doing so I still manage to browse /scripts without any error.

So it seems it isn't an .htaccess problem, maybe has something to do with permission? The Magento root and all its subfolders are of course not readable, but then how can I create a browsable subdirectory?

Is there maybe a folder inside Magento where I can run my custom scripts or how can I create a readable subfolder in Magento root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this: the subfolder didn't have and index.php file so Apache tried to read the folder tree which is forbidden.

So you just have to add an index.php file to the subfolder, what a silly mistake!